# MySQL query user conversations with other people

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query conversations of specific user with others.

The table record every message info like user id of sender and receiver:

```sql
CREATE TABLE now_user_chat (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id',
  `to_uid` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'send to user id',
  `speak_time` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'speak time',
  `content` varchar(600) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `to_uid` (`to_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

!! The records are out of order:

```
| id | uid | to_uid | speak_time |  content |
|----|-----|--------|------------|----------|
|  1 |   1 |      2 |          10 | [0102] A |
|  2 |   2 |      1 |          20 | [0102] B |
|  3 |   2 |      1 |          30 | [0102] D |
|  4 |   1 |      3 |          40 | [0103] A |
|  5 |   2 |      3 |          50 | [0203] A |
|  6 |   3 |      1 |          60 | [0103] B |
|  7 |   4 |      3 |          70 | [0304] A |
|  8 |   3 |      4 |          80 | [0304] B |
|  9 |   2 |      4 |          90 | [0204] A |
| 10 |   1 |      3 |         100 | [0103] C |
| 11 |   1 |      2 |         110 | [0102] D |
| 12 |   2 |      1 |          120 | [0102] C |
| 13 |   2 |      1 |          25 | [0102] C |
```

The onlie [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edbe94/2)

I want to query user id `1`'s conversations with others by target group and `speak_time` less than `110` and order by `speak_time` asc. The result looks like this:

Records in target group are ordered by `speak_time` asc, which can be showed in timeline.

```
| id | target_group | uid    | to_uid | speak_time |  content |
|----|--------------|--------|--------|------------|----------|
|  1 |  2           |   1    |      2 |          10 | [0102] A |
|  2 |  2           |   2    |      1 |          20 | [0102] B |
| 13 |  2           |   2    |      1 |          25 | [0102] C |
|  3 |  2           |   2    |      1 |          30 | [0102] D |
|  4 |  3           |   1    |      3 |          40 | [0103] A |
|  6 |  3           |   3    |      1 |          60 | [0103] B |
| 10 |  3           |   1    |      3 |         100 | [0103] C |
```

How can I write the SQL query?

-------- Edit ----------

`target_group` is just the person who talked to user id `1`, and there only one table.

Comment: If your target_group is from another table than you can just use join statements of mysql for this.

Comment: This seems to be a simple join (information on the other table  containing target groups missing), where criteria and order by. You really should make an attempt at resolving this question yourself).

Comment: It needs to consider `speak_time` order and target group, which is not easy to novice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is what you want..

```
select * from now_user_chat where (uid = 1 or to_uid =1 ) and speak_time < 11
```

SQL fiddle demo [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45e1466/2) 
[image]

Comment: I want to group people who talked to user `1`, so I can show the conversations with others in timeline. And the records are out of order

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
select
    x.id,
    (case when x.uid = 1 then x.to_uid else x.uid end) as target_group,
    x.uid,
    x.to_uid,
    x.speak_time,
    x.content 
from now_user_chat x
where (x.uid = 1 or x.to_uid = 1)
    and x.speak_time < 11
order by x.speak_time asc;
```

Comment: Thanks. But the records are out of order, so I need to group and order by `speak_time` asc.